# Is there a way to set priorities among classes in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

Is there a way to set priorities among classes execution in TestNG?
*Is there some annotation or xml settings?*
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in testng.xml file. Order of classes is important in the file, and just run directly this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test(priority = 1) 
public void testMethodA() { 
   System.out.println("Executing - testMethodA");
} 
@Test 
public void testMethodB() { 
   System.out.println("Executing - testMethodB");
}
@Test(priority = 2) 
public void testMethodC() { 
   System.out.println("Executing - testMethodC");
}
```

Output

1. Executing - testMethodB
2. Executing - testMethodA
3. Executing-testMethodC

> testMethodB got executed first as it had a default priority of 0